# Command line utility to run code in a web app

Tags: java, web-applications, command-line

I just got a requirement to create a small (I assume standalone) utility to hit some code in our web application to do some custom processing of files from the app and then dump the files into a shared drive. My question is what is the best way for doing this? Do I just create a small app and then jar it up and run it off a command line or is there a better way?

Sorry, I didn't give enough detail. It's an old application, like over 10 years, so while it's been upgraded to jdk 1.6, most of the code uses the old collections, old loops, etc... There aren't any interfaces, very tightly coupled code that uses inheritance with lots of nested objects. The web app will do the processing. I think what they want is create some code outside of the application code that will login and then fire off the file processing code. Prior to this I had upgraded their version of Windward Reports in a separate branch and they want to make sure that the processed files: contracts, forms, etc.. don't get altered greatly as there are legal requirements on fonts and layouts. So this utility will go in, fire off the list of reports (a few thousand) dump it to a share drive so they can view them with another tool for comparision based on rules you can automate with that commercial tool, en masse. I was thinking create a small class with a main method, then jar it up and while the web server is running with my upgraded branch code, run the utility off the command line to fire it off.

Comment: Is your web application the one that will do all the processing? If so you can look at something simple like wget or curl, `wget http://example.com/myprocess.jsp?parameters-to-pass-in=1 -O output_of_process.log`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I was originally looking at creating a standalone utility jar that I would run off the command line to connect with URLConnection  to the app, but I found there is already testing code built into the application that I can run from a command line as long as I deploy the new code with the existing code. The utility will dump out the files to a shared drive and then XTest can be run to compare files. After reviewing the capabilities of XTest, it appears that it can handle the comparison of files well.

Answer (score 0):

There's not enough to go on here. How is the web app's functions exposed? If it's a REST interface then wget/curl/spring-rest-template are the way to go. If it's something like a JFS app then you're going to need something like [Selenium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_%28software%29) to imitate a browser. If the functionality is in a shared library (JAR) then there web never even comes into play.